# Jquery FadeIn and FadeOut

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to fadeout a div element, change the text inside of it, and fade it back in...

The code I have is here -

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#l2").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#1").fadeOut();
                $("#1").replaceWith('Testing');
                $("#1").fadeIn();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

l2 is clicked and it will fadeOut div id 1 replace and fade back in...but it's failing..ANy help thanks!

Comment: Numeric IDs are not recommended...

Comment: The `div` ID must start with a letter

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it is failing?

Comment: What is 'Testing'?  what are you trying to replace?

Comment: @Darcy no it mustn't http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global#Core_Attributes

Comment: yea i changed them for example to be shorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `.text` or `.html` rather than `.replaceWith` -- that's for working with DOM elements.  Also, `.text` and `.html` do not work with the queue, so you can't chain them.  You have to use the callbacks:

```
$("#1").fadeOut(function () {
   $(this).text('Testing').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callbacks to achieve your goal:

```
$("#1").fadeOut(500, function(){
     $("#1").html('Testing');
     $("#1").fadeIn();
});
```

The function passed as a parameter will be executed when the fadeOut completes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fadeout callback.  Here is a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M5PnY/2/  click the text

edit------

changed replace with html(), didn't see it before

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#1").fadeOut(function(event){
            $("#1").html('Testing').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Does not work because `.replaceWith` removes the ID.  Notice that it doesn't fade in.

Answer (score 0):

In the second row you replace the element #1 with something new, then you can't fade it back in again.

```
$("#1").replaceWith('Testing');
```

results in div#1 is replaced by the text Testing

so you should instead use :

```
$("#1").html('Testing');
```